# Why does Django return Django object is not iterable error?

Tags: python, django

What am i getting [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dAsTe.png) error for ?

models.py

```
class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    description = models.TextField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class SubCategory(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    image_url = models.CharField(default=0, max_length=2000)
    price = models.IntegerField(default=0)
```

views.py

```
def category(request, pk):
    categories = Category.objects.get(id=pk)
    subcategories = SubCategory.objects.filter(category=categories)
    return render(request, 'category.html', {'categories': categories, 'subcategories': subcategories})
```

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index),
    url(r'^category/(?P<pk>\d+)$', views.category, name='category'),
]
```

base.html

```
{% for category in categories %}
<a class="dropdown-item" href="{% url 'category' pk=category.id %}">{{ category.name }}</a>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: unrelated but you can use `category.subcategory_set.all()` instead of manually filtering.

Answer (score 2):

`get` returns a model instance, not a queryset (despite your misleading variable name):

```
categories = Category.objects.get(id=pk)  # instance, not queryset!
```

Hence:

```
{% for category in categories %}  # instance cannot be looped over!
```

produces the error that you encoutered.

Comment: Just `{{ categories.name }}` without a loop, for starters. But you should really change the name of that context variable to a singular one.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to get only one `Category` object in below file.

**views.py**

```
def category(request, pk):
        categories = Category.objects.get(id=pk) # Here you trying to get category
        subcategories = SubCategory.objects.filter(category=categories)
        return render(request, 'category.html', {
            'categories': categories, # categories is single object not iterable
            'subcategories': subcategories})
```

For solution you can either set `categories = Category.objects.filter(id=pk)` to your **views.py** or update your **html template**.

Answer (score 0):

because, my error was related with queryset. what does it mean ? an array. and each array has its indexes, so, in this example, our 'categories' is an array and we must assign its first ([0]) index to a category:

```
def category(request, pk):
        categories = Category.objects.get(id=pk)
        subcategories = SubCategory.objects.filter(category=categories[0])
        return render(request, 'category.html', {'categories': categories, 'subcategories': subcategories})
```

Comment: Please consider adding a description of your code so we know what it does and why.